# How to fix this error Class 'List<items>' has no instance getter 'fruitsItemsList'. Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to add items to shopping cart and I get this Error :

Class 'List' has no instance getter 'fruitsItemsList'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: fruitsItemsList

here is my code lines to add them:

```
return StreamBuilder(// and it shows me erorr here two I do not know why? 
   //to add selected items to shopping cart
    stream: bloc.listStream,
    // ignore: missing_return
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     // if loop to check snapshot not empty 
      if (snapshot.data != null) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    //to count the items that selected 
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems.length,  // i think the erorr here 
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return Single_cart_product(
                        prodName:  snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems[index].name,//to get item's name 
                        prodPrice: snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems[index].price, //to get item's price
                        prodPic:   snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems[index].picture, //to get item picture
                        prodQun:   snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems[index].quantity, //to get item quantity
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    });
```

and this is my items_List.dart:

```
FruitsItemsList fruitsItemsList = FruitsItemsList(fruitsItems: [
  item(
    id: 001,
    name: "kiwi",
    picture: "assets/kiwi1.jpg",
    price: 7,
  ),

]);

class FruitsItemsList {

  List<item> fruitsItems;
  FruitsItemsList({@required this.fruitsItems});
}

class item {
  int id;
  String name;
  double price;
  String picture;
  int quantity;

  item({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.picture,
    this.quantity = 1,
  });

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please rename class items as item, to more accurately represent that it is a single item in that object.

Comment: done it ,Sorry for that

Comment: and it is not only single item, there are 5.

Comment: Each item is an item though.  It's not an "items"! You have a List<item> which looks like [item, item, item, item, item].

Comment: so is that going to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Streambuilder without a type cast is a standard List type when it returns the snapshot.  Cast it like this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Item>>
```

Then snapShot.data will be a list of Item.   When you call snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems It is the same as List.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems.  The List object has no method fruitsItemsList.

Comment: no Sir, and I have solved it, the problem was in this line `itemCount: snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems.length,` I just did it `snapshot.data.length`  and it works

Comment: Thank you for trying to help ;)